# Появление элемента при условии

Tags: html, jquery

Нужно чтобы появилась кнопка при условии, что если хотя бы один из параграфов в блоке имеет класс .clicked. Вот то, до чего смог додуматься...:
И кнопка почему то появляется сразу, хотя ни одного p с классом .clicked нет.

```js
 $("p").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
 });
  if ($(".block").find("p.clicked")) {
    $('button').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $('button').css('display', 'none');
  };
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .2s;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
</div>

<button>Готово!</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует поместить условие в функцию, чтобы проверка происходила при каждом клике, а не единожды - при загрузке страницы:

```js
 $("p").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    if ($(".clicked").length) {
      $('button').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $('button').css('display', 'none');
    };
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .2s;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
</div>

<button>Готово!</button>
```